# Change the selected day background color

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-styles, android-datepicker

I've been trying to stylize a `DatePicker` -- **NOT** `DatePickerDialog`, if that matters -- without any success.

The problem I'm facing is this:

[image]

As you can see, the selected day background is black. I've tried to apply the following style:

```
<style name="DatePickerStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary"> @color/Red </item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark"> @color/Blue </item>
    <item name="colorAccent"> @color/Green </item>
</style>
```

But I would only get errors like:

```
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'
```

and

```
Error retrieving parent for item:
    No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
```

I've tried to do it via code, but so far the only thing I've managed to stylize was the header background, by doing something like this:

```
( ( datePicker.GetChildAt( 0 ) as LinearLayout ).GetChildAt( 0 ) as LinearLayout )
    .SetBackgroundResource( Utils.AppColorResourceId );
```

or, by direct `id`

```
datePicker.FindViewById( 16909081 ).SetBackgroundResource( Utils.AppColorResourceId );
```

Although I'm avoiding the later mostly because I'm afraid the id changes with the device/OS version.

---

So my question is: **How can I change the colour used to mark the selected day?
 Is there a way to do it via code? If so, how is it?** ( *I'd like to change the colour at runtime due to some actions the user can do to change the colour* )

---

### EDIT

#### Styles.xml

```
...

<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Blue</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/Red</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/Red</item>
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/Blue</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/Green</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/Base</item>
</style>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for changing your selected date color

```
    <style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!-- this is new -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/prim</item>
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/primDark</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/primDark</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    <item name="android:minDate">01/01/2000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No luck with the code you provided, the selected day was still black.

Comment: what color your are using as your "android:colorAccent"

Comment: I've tried some from my `Colors.xml` file. Here's one of them: `<color name="Base"> #FFC85D36 </color>`

Comment: can you post your style.xml?

Comment: @auhmaan have you noticed any change in your style and mine change your colorAccent value to your color for selected date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144249/discussion-between-auhmaan-and-sandeep-dhiman).

Answer (score 0):

Override datePickerDialogTheme inside your app's base theme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
....
<item 
  name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
 </style>
```

here is your MyDatePickerDialogTheme

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" 
 parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
 </style>
```

We have overridden datePickerStyle with the style MyDatePickerStyle. The choice of parent will once again depend on what your app's base theme is: either Widget.Material.DatePicker or Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker. Define it as per your requirements:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
<item name="android:headerBackground">@color/chosen_header_bg_color</item>
```

with this you can also have some more customization i listed bellow

```
dayOfWeekBackground
dayOfWeekTextAppearance
headerMonthTextAppearance
headerDayOfMonthTextAppearance
headerYearTextAppearance
headerSelectedTextColor
yearListItemTextAppearance
yearListSelectorColor
```

If you don't want this much control (customization), you don't need to override datePickerStyle. colorAccent controls most of the DatePicker's colors. So, overriding just colorAccent inside MyDatePickerDialogTheme should work:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/date_picker_accent</item>

<!-- No need to override 'datePickerStyle' -->
<!-- <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item> -->
```